# Convert date (c#)

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Good day! Faced with the problem. Need to convert the date. In the database it is stored in the format:

```
1332622254
1332622368
1332622467
1332622551
```

I am with this format never encountered. What is this format, I do not know. Help to format it in vfeueshu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be the number of seconds since some date (maybe 1-1-1970)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a time in seconds since midnight 1-1-1970:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1332622254);
var date = epoch.Add(ts);
```

`date` is then 24-3-2012 20:50:54

**EDIT**
Or simpler, as MarcinJuraszek rightly stated:

```
var epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
var date = epoch.AddSeconds(1332622254);
```

Note that this might be a date/time in UTC, so maybe you will have to adjust for your timezone.

Comment: Why not just `DateTime().AddSeconds()`?

Answer (score 0):

It's [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
TimeSpan a = new TimeSpan(1332622254);
```

Comment: Note that this TimeSpan constructor uses the number of *ticks*.

Comment: See below answer of Hans Kesting. I suppose he is right in this case.